# Not Unless or No unless

Tags: grammar

I have one question when you the word " Unless "
I saw it in my textbook as following :

A: Hey Tim, My I tell your story with Barch.
B: Not unless he asks you about it.

Why they use Not here? May I use "No" like: 
" No unless he ask you.

Please explain it. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me answer

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those responses are complete sentences, so in both cases there are implied words. Both "not" and "no" could be correct depending on what words are assumed to be omitted from what would be a complete sentence.

> (You may) not unless he asks you.
>
> No, (you may not) unless he asks you.

Either could be correct, but the first phrasing is more natural. "Not unless he asks you" would come together in a complete sentence, whereas "No, unless he asks you" is not a continuous series of words in the complete sentence.